# How to use the output of a Linux command as a if/else statement in python

Tags: python-2.7, debian-jessie

Last week I started using python for writing install scripts for my raspberry pi 3. 
I installed debian jessie on my pi and within debian I'm using exagear.

When I start the script, I would like to realize that the code could check in which architecture it's running. With the 'arch' command in Debian I can see it's 'armv71' and within exagear it's 'i686'.
I have two different functions in python, one for the 'armv71' architecture and one for the 'i686' architecture. I would activate them by using a if and else statement.
Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Check what `popen` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use subprocess module

```
import subprocess

myoutput = subprocess.check_output(["arch"])

if myoutput=='x86_64\n':
    print 'this is x86'
else:
    print 'something else...'
```